# Discounting configurable product in Magento 2

Tags: magento-2.1

How am I supposed to discount configurable products in Magento 2.1?

Price is gone from the configurable, so I can't do it there. Applying catalog rules to subproducts is not a option anymore either.

So do I really have to update 35 variants individually if I want to reduce the price for an item?

Answer (score 0):

In Magento2, simple products under configurables can have their own prices - no longer do they inherit pricing from the configurable product.

I would suggest doing a bulk update via admin:

Go to products.

- Select the scope (view dropdown) to choose which site pricing is applied to - leave as is if single store.
- Select the items you wish to update
- In the actions dropdown select 'Update Attributes' and then find 'Special Price' when the edit screen is displayed.
- Click change and update the price.  Save product.

Either this or update using a script, csv upload, API?

Comment: That will work, although it seems like a step back in terms of making Magento easier to work with.

Comment: I think it's more flexible in the sense that you can have different prices for variations under the configurable. A lot better than Magento 1's configurable options anyway.

Comment: BAF that was possible in Magento 1 as well. They have not added anything, only taken away.

Comment: In Magento 1 the simple products inherited their price from the parent product.  So pricing was irrelevant.  You could only have the simple product price displayed by extending Magento.